# How can I get the used prefix from a Jena Resource?

Tags: rdf, jena

Given a Jena Resource object (`org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource`), how can I get the prefix of the Resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resource and prefix are unrelated things. To work with prefixes there is a `org.apache.jena.shared.PrefixMapping` interface. Any model (`org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model`) extends PrefixMapping. Also a graph (`org.apache.jena.graph.Graph`) provides access to the PrefixMapping.

To get prefix from uri the method PrefixMapping#getNsURIPrefix(String) can be used. To get an URI from resource there is a #getURI method, which will return null in case it is anonymous resource.

The PrefixMapping#getNsURIPrefix(String) will return the most recently added prefix, which does not guarantee it was the associated with the Resource.
[image]

src:https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/shared/PrefixMapping.html#getNsURIPrefix-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added that there's no guarantee about getNsURIPrefix() because they're not related.